# How to print a pandas dataframe in the tkinter table format?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
dic = {"NAME": name, "DURATION": duration, "START": start, "FINISH": finish, "REWATCH": rewatch, "COMMENT": comment}

def openNewWindow3(): newWindow=tk.Toplevel(m) newWindow.title("Your Library") newWindow.minsize(600,800) newWindow.configure(bg='#F0FFFF') df = pd.DataFrame(dic) cols = list(df.columns)

 tree = ttk.Treeview(newWindow)
 tree.pack(fill="both")
 tree["columns"] = cols
 for i in cols:
     
     tree.column(i, anchor="w")
     tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')

 for index, row in df.iterrows():
     tree.insert("", 0, text=index, values=list(row))
```

I could make this code, but I don't really understand it. It has a lot of things that don't work: I can't change the column name or control its width and the input is done in reverse. It also doesn't look really neat.

I have a lot of other functions that enter the value and things and they work fine.

I've been searching a lot for this, but I couldn't find anything! I'm  completely new to tkinter and python.

Comment: try this link https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-display-data-in-a-table-using-tkinter/

Comment: hey i tried the last option! this came out https://imgur.com/a/IWZEMin

Comment: You can change the field names of `dic` to change the column names and change the column widths using `tree.column(i, anchor='w', width=...)`.  So I don't understand what the problem is.